# How many people watched the moon landings after Apollo 11?

Tags: spaceflight, television

I'm currently writing an essay on the history of Spaceflight. I remember hearing before that interest in the Apollo program waned after Apollo 11, that TV ratings of the moon missions gradually dwindled from public apathy, with the exception of Apollo 13. However, *I can't find any contemporary evidence which shows that public interest in Apollo's subsequent missions to the moon faded.* I'm having such a hard time proving this in my essay. I know that the Apollo 11 mission had around 600 million viewers when Armstrong and Aldrin touched down. That data is out there and is easy enough to find. And it seems pretty obvious to me that people stopped caring shortly thereafter. But what I'm really interested in is some kind of hard proof which shows that people stopped caring about the moon missions.

So far, my googling hasn't helped, though I've found a number of cool sources. None of the following solved my problem:

1. A website devoted to classic TV ratings: http://www.classictvhits.com/tvratings/
2. Various television ratings archives: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_U.S._television_ratings_archives
3. Apollo by the Numbers - a super cool site showing all kinds of useful stats pertaining to the Apollo missions: https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4029/Apollo_00a_Cover.htm
4. Historical Nielson TV ratings: https://guides.libraries.psu.edu/nielsen/historical

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is tricky because you have to consider that the amount of coverage varied, as did the time of key moments which were most viewer-friendly (networks were loathe to interrupt prime time too much). In other words, it's not like comparing and observing declining ratings for TV shows which are generally broadcast in the same time slot and which are the same duration.

Comment: Not an answer but possibly relevant; the Apollo 12 TV camera was damaged early in the mission so there was little coverage of the EVAs - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_12#EVAs   Also, on Apollo 13 the TV networks had very limited coverage until the 'problem' - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_13#Launch_and_translunar_injection

Comment: They (obviously) stopped watching them because [it's quite depressing to think that there's nothing left out there, to see and discover anymore](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLxpNiF0YKs&t=224)...